# Passing Angular Formly model to c# Controller

Tags: c#, angularjs, angular-formly

I have an AngularJS app that is using formly to generate a form. Below is an example of the model data.

```
{
  "form_field_17": "None Required",
  "title": 1,
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "email": "john@gmail.com",
  "mobile": "1234567890",
}
```

What kind of object should I use in my C# controller to receive this? I can't have a pre-defined class, as the controller should be able to accept any type of json data.

Comment: You can accept `string` if you feel like doing it without any model binding. Model binding wouldn't get you anything in this case anyway, because the properties can be anything at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really want to be able to accept ANY type of ***valid*** JSON (and there are probably good business and security rules for NOT doing this) and you want to deserialize *before* reaching the method (rather than accepting the raw JSON string), then you're down to two options.

`JToken`, if using Newtonsoft Json.NET:

```
public ResultType DynamicPayloadEndpoint(JToken dynamicObject)
```

or use the actual `dynamic` keyword:

```
public ResultType DynamicPayloadEndpoint(dynamic dynamicObject)
```

How you handle exposing that data at that point will always be tricky, but you'll be able to accept anything.

Keep in mind that if using ASP.NET MVC, this makes modelbinding useless.

Comment: Thanks. Since we want to be able to create any type of form (which means the json fields submitted would be different between forms), can you suggest what to do instead of accepting any valid JSON?

Comment: @user1024941 I'd use separate endpoints per form.  Typically a `POST` or `PUT` endpoint has a specific business function, so using a specific endpoint per form (business action) is typically a healthy separation of concerns.  it also allows you to authorize and authenticate per endpoint if you so choose.

Comment: New forms can be created at any time though. I need a dynamic solution.

Comment: @user1024941 then you're down to what I outlined in my answer above and you'll have to handle the object based on use cases further downstream.